# PowerShell can't see network locations after SQLPS module is loaded

Tags: networking, powershell, sql-server

I'm trying to automate a script that backups a database in one environment, copies it to the other, then restores it there. But there's some strange behavior going on.

First, I try to access a network location. Works like a bliss:

```
C:\> Get-ChildItem \\remote-server\e$
```

Returns

```
Directory: \\remote-server\e$
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         19-3-2015     11:49            Program Files
```

However, as soon as I import the Sqlps module (which is the collection of SQL Server Management Objects - SMO) for interacting with the database, the networked locations can't be found anymore:

```
PS C:\> Import-Module Sqlps -DisableNameChecking;
PS SQLSERVER:\> Get-ChildItem \\remote-server\e$
```

Returns:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\remote-server\e$' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem \\remote-server\e$
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\remote-server\e$:String)[Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Accessing regular file locations is no problem and just works.

How can I access network locations after having loaded the SQLPS module / SMO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the `Import-Module Sqlps -DisableNameChecking;` command, your current location is immediately changed to `PS SQLSERVER:\>`. Being "in" SQLSERVER prevents you from using `Get-ChildItem` related to a drive location.

First, you will need to change your current location back to a drive location with `Set-Location` or `cd`. Then, you will be able to use `Get-ChildItem` for the folder, then navigate back to `SQLSERVER:\` (if necessary):

Example:

```
PS C:\ > Import-Module Sqlps -DisableNameChecking;
PS SQLSERVER:\> Set-Location C:\
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem \\remote-server\e$
PS C:\> Set-Location SQLSERVER:\
```

I should also note that the behavior of changing your location on importing the module is [a bug that was fixed in SQL Server 2016](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2434605/loading-sqlps-module-changes-current-directory-to-ps-sqlserver/). In the future, your current location would **not** be switched to `SQLSERVER:\`, so you would not need to `Set-Location` back to a drive location.

Answer (score 0):

AS @AMtwo already mentioned, the reason is you're "in" SQL Server, where the `Get-ChildItem`, but also other concepts like `Move-Item` apply to SQL Server object (as opposed to filesystem-objects).

To force the cmdlets to use the locations you provided as filesystem-locations, you could prepend the path with `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::` like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\remote-server\e$"
```

Now, PowerShell tries to access the path like a filesystem-path, and the network-path is available again.